# Need Explanation of these check property of Provisioning profile Apple

Tags: ios, xcode

I am creating Apple certificates, In it i have below options added to check mark.
Please explain use of it 
[image]

Comment: Now you can enable these in Xcode - Project Settings - Capabilities. And I think you need a tutorial.

Comment: Refer this Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html

Comment: @i know i can enable it, but if enable push notification from here need to create APNS certificates as well or it automatically use its feature just a single check ?

Comment: To use push notification you need to create APNS certificate. Not the check mark alone give you push notifications. It only enables the push property for the AppID.

Comment: @ron27 thanks....but i i need to create separate push for each bundle identifier ? or just APNS in apple account ?

Comment: @iphonemaclover Yes, you need to create separate APNS certificate for each bundle identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this apple documentation
[Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

[image]